# Cargo fails with "spurious network error: The operation timed out" on Windows 10 when using a local user

Tags: rust, windows-10, rust-cargo

I'm trying to setup a Rust programming environment for a local user on a Windows 10 laptop that is usually connected to my company domain. Installing the stable version of Rust with `rustup` via `rustup-init.exe` completed without problems, but every time I try to use `cargo` to install tools or libraries I get an error message like the following:

```
warning: spurious network error (5 tries remaining): [2/-1] failed to send request: The operation timed out
```

This happens both from my company network and from my home one. I managed to setup Rust for my domain account without problems.

I suppose this is network related or it might involve the Sophos software my company uses as firewall/anti-virus; what is puzzling me is the fact that just about every other network related utility I tried works without problems, from `git` to `curl`.

I'd like to use this additional user because there are utilities my company blocks for domain users but not for local ones, such as Dropbox.

Comment: Have you already read https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/636? Do you have a proxy? Have you tried looking at the logs for any network utilities that block outgoing / incoming connections?

Comment: Yes, I did read that, but I do not have a proxy at home. I'll have to try and find relevant logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a definite explanation, but `cargo` works correctly when the VPN towards my office is active. I guess it really is something to do with security software.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I used a proxy once and it was set as a variable in CMD.
To show your proxy settings, in an administrator cmd type:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

if you have one you can reset it by:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

Comment: This was already covered in the comments of the original answer, where the author of the question indicates he doesn't use a proxy at home.

Comment: I changed the proxy once and when I stop using the proxy, the winhttp params of cmd stayed. It is worth making sure that it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a good hour trying to figure this out and came across 2 potential solutions

1. There could be an issue with ssh: dependency, fixed it by starting ssh agent:

```sh
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add
cargo build
```

2. setup in a global ~/.gitconfig

```sh
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

Removing this in `~/.gitconfig` also solved the issue